# Inform JavaScript of user being active in PowerBI embedded

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a PowerBI report embedded on a page within my site. I have a 20 minute timeout on my site that will log the user out after 20 minutes of inactivity.

Unfortunately, since the user being active within the PowerBI embedded report doesn't make any calls to my server, the server thinks that the user has been inactive and logs them out.

Is there a way in PowerBI embedded to notify the Javascript on the page it is hosted in, to tell it that the user has clicked on buttons or selected charts, or generally been active? If so I can then make a call to a heartbeat API endpoint on my server that will keep their session alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen for the events currently exposed by the [powerbi-client library](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events). It probably won't cover all user actions, but it may be sufficient.